# Use pip with non-standard Python installation (non-root installation)?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to get up and running with Python 3.5.2 and various packages on a server I work on, but don't have root privileges for. I installed Python to my `home`, and that seems to be working. I'm trying to set it up so I can install packages to that Python installation (ie `~/lib/python3.5/site-packages`) via `pip`, but I cannot get it working.

Even after adding `~/lib/python3.5/site-packages` to `$PYTHONPATH`, no luck.

Running `pip install pandas`, I get the error `/usr/local/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` , so it's still looking in the wrong spot. It should be looking at `~/bin/python3.5`. Setting an `--install-option="--prefix=` argument doesn't change the problem.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Check which pip you are using, e.g. `which pip`. It probably is the one that comes with your system python. You need to install pip for your own interpreter and use that to install pandas

Comment: tried this already, it's using the correct pip. ie `which pip` returns `~/bin/pip3.5`. I aliased pip to pip3.5.

Comment: To make sure `pip` is installed for your target `python`, use `~/bin/python3.5 -m ensurepip`. Additionally, `~/bin/python3.5 -m pip install ...` will always point to the correct `pip` installation for your Python 3.5.

Comment: Ah! This seems to do it!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
pip3 install --user "library name"
```